# Сворачивать/разворачивать окно по кнопке

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Вот код для сворачивания/разворачивания окна по кнопке home. Но, окно разворачивается, сворачивается, и больше не максимизируется. Где ошибка?

```
static bool display(true);
static RECT rect;

.......

case WM_KEYDOWN:
{
    if (wParam == VK_HOME)
    {
        if (display)
        {
            GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
            ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
        }
        else
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        display = display ? false : true;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте следующий код: `if (wParam == VK_HOME)
 {ShowWindow(hwnd, display ? SW_MAXIMIZE : SW_MINIMIZE); display = !display;}`. Это если вы хотите всегда восстанавливать в развёрнутый вид. Если же восстанавливать надо в вид до сворачивания, замените `SW_MAXIMIZE` на `SW_RESTORE`.

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, что там не работает. Но проблема решена.